# xUnit : Assert two List<T> are equal?

Tags: c#, xunit

I'm new to TDD and xUnit so I want to test my method that looks something like:

```
List<T> DeleteElements<T>(this List<T> a, List<T> b);
```

Is there any Assert method that I can use ? I think something like this would be nice

```
List<int> values = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
List<int> expected = new List<int>() { 1 };
List<int> actual = values.DeleteElements(new List<int>() { 2, 3 });

Assert.Exact(expected, actual);
```

Is there something like this ?

Answer (score 210, accepted):

#### 2021-Apr-01 update

I recommend using [FluentAssertions](https://fluentassertions.com/). It has a vast IntelliSense-friendly assertion library for many use cases including [collections](https://fluentassertions.com/collections/)

```
collection.Should().Equal(1, 2, 5, 8);
collection.Should().NotEqual(8, 2, 3, 5);
collection.Should().BeEquivalentTo(8, 2, 1, 5);
```

---

#### Original answer

**xUnit.Net** recognizes collections so you just need to do

```
Assert.Equal(expected, actual); // Order is important
```

You can see other available collection assertions in [CollectionAsserts.cs](https://github.com/xunit/assert.xunit/blob/master/CollectionAsserts.cs)

For **NUnit** library collection comparison methods are

```
CollectionAssert.AreEqual(IEnumerable, IEnumerable) // For sequences, order matters
```

and

```
CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(IEnumerable, IEnumerable) // For sets, order doesn't matter
```

More details here: [CollectionAssert](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Collection-Assert)

**MbUnit** also has collection assertions similar to NUnit: [Assert.Collections.cs](https://github.com/Gallio/mbunit-v3/blob/master/src/MbUnit/MbUnit/Framework/Assert.Collections.cs)

Comment: Source code link changed for http://xunit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/d947e347c5c3#Samples%2fAssertExamples%2fCollectionExample.cs

Comment: New link in comments broken too.

Comment: Project is now moved to GitHub, but I haven't been able to find that particular source file there either.

Comment: For complex object don't forget that you need an Equal+GetHasCode for this to work or give the Equal method a custom EqulityComparer

Comment: xUnit Equal method returns false for two IEnumerables with equal content.

Answer (score 46):

In the current version of XUnit (1.5) you can just use

> Assert.Equal(expected, actual);

The above method will do an element by element comparison of the two lists.
I'm not sure if this works for any prior version.

Comment: The problem I encountered with Assert.Equal for collections is that it fails if the collections' elements are in different orders, even if the elements are present in both.

Comment: @ScottA.Lawrence Lists have order too! Do you get the same behavior with HashSets?

Comment: @johv I haven't tested it with HashSets, but that's a good idea.  Once I've had a chance to try it I'll try to remember to answer here.

Comment: HashSets are still compared in order

Comment: It also seems to fail if the collection types are different, even if they both contain the same items in the same order.

Comment: @James White It's cause of default Equals comparator. You must override default Equals() and GetHashCode()

Comment: But it has a very crappy output. It does not tell you WHERE two lists differ! :(

Comment: @ScottLawrence LINQ is a good friend here, e.g. expected.OrderBy(x => x.something) and then the same on sut exec result collection.

Comment: @Zordid An alternative might be to `Zip` the two together, and then iterate over every pair, calling `Assert.Equal` on each.

Comment: @Zordid There's a fixed issue filed [here](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/994) and it's been fixed since 2.4.2-pre.9

Answer (score 25):

With xUnit, should you want to cherry pick properties of each element to test you can use Assert.Collection.

```
Assert.Collection(elements, 
  elem1 => Assert.Equal(expect1, elem1.SomeProperty),
  elem2 => { 
     Assert.Equal(expect2, elem2.SomeProperty);
     Assert.True(elem2.TrueProperty);
  });
```

This tests the expected count and ensures that each action is verified.

Answer (score 6):

In the current version of xUnit [v2.4.2](https://xunit.net/releases/2.4.2) you can also use:

```cs
Assert.Equivalent(expected: ..., actual: ..., strict: true);
```

> The `strict` parameter influences this comparison by requiring that all values in the `expected` list are in the `actual` list (meaning `expected: [1, 2]` is equivalent to `actual: [2, 3, 1]` when `strict` is `false`, but not equivalent when `strict` is `true`).

Comment: this should be voted higher. it does not rely on third party packages but uses only xUnit, which is clearly required in the question.

Answer (score 5):

Recently, I was using `xUnit 2.4.0` and `Moq 4.10.1` packages in my asp.net core 2.2 app.

In my case I managed to get it work with two steps process:

1. Defining an implementation of `IEqualityComparer<T>`
2. Pass the comparer instance as a third parameter into `Assert.True` method:

   `Assert.True(expected, actual, new MyEqualityComparer());`

But there is another nicer way to get the same result using [FluentAssertions](https://fluentassertions.com/) package. It allows you to do the following:

```
// Assert          
expected.Should().BeEquivalentTo(actual));
```

Interestingly that `Assert.Equal()` always fails even when I ordered the elements of two lists to get them in the same order.

Comment: something is wrong with your ordering BeEquivalentTo doesnt care about order (thats why your test passes with BeEquivalentTo and not with assert.Equal)

Answer (score 2):

Just found the NotStrictEqual that seems to do it.

Comment: NotStrictEqual might pass, but it will also pass when given two arrays with no common elements at all. It's not a useful assertion for this problem.