# Why is test failing on HashSet comparison, where the ordering of elements seems to matter

Tags: c#, collections, equals, hashset

I have tests which show the following xUnit.net output:

```
[xUnit.net 00:00:07.1166826]       Expected: HashSet<License> [Comp.Licensing.Web.Model.License [5d8104ef-f707-4a40-9d68-463bf9f8b0f9], Comp.Licensing.Web.Model.License [d586fc23-bba6-474c-82a2-226484d7fb81]]
[xUnit.net 00:00:07.1172482]       Actual:   HashSet<License> [Comp.Licensing.Web.Model.License [d586fc23-bba6-474c-82a2-226484d7fb81], Comp.Licensing.Web.Model.License [5d8104ef-f707-4a40-9d68-463bf9f8b0f9]]
```

What I don't understand is why this test is failing, and seemingly the reason is that the HashSet is out of order.

Specifically, it appear that the **Actual** is exactly the same as the **Expected.

Actual:

```
HashSet<L> [Stuff [abc], Stuff [123]]
```

Expected:

```
HashSet<L> [Stuff [123], Stuff [abc]]
```

On the doc for [HashSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), it says

> A set is a collection that contains no duplicate elements, and whose elements are in no particular order.

Are my tests being run by something that's not using the same equality check for HashSet?

Comment: How about posting your tests so that we can see what may be wrong instead of trying to guess...

Comment: Are you checking that two HashSet object references are the same object, or that two HashSet objects have the same contents? What kind of equality are you testing for?

Comment: Sorry @L.B, I'll put an edit explaining my confusion.  What I don't understand is that the **Expected** HashSet in that message is the same as the **Actual**

Comment: @hatchet That two HashSets have the same contents

Comment: @rt2 Just copy this code and test it..It is 3 lines of code. VS will help you.  `var equal1 = new HashSet<int>(new[] { 1, 2 }) == new HashSet<int>(new[] { 1, 2 });
            var equal2 = new HashSet<int>(new[] { 1, 2 }).SequenceEqual(new HashSet<int>(new[] { 2, 1 }));
            var equal3 = new HashSet<int>(new[] { 1, 2 }).OrderBy(x=>x).SequenceEqual(new HashSet<int>(new[] { 2, 1 }).OrderBy(x=>x));`

Comment: "Are my tests being run by something that's not using the same equality check for HashSet?"

What are you using to test the equality of your HashSets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HashSet` does not override `Equals`, and will use `object.Equals`, which is reference equality.

`HashSet` give no guarantee on the order of the elements.

If you are using `Assert.Equal`, then the order of the collections matter.

Instead use `CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent`.

Source: [xUnit : Assert two List<T> are equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419659/xunit-assert-two-listt-are-equal)